# Hide a portion of page and show it in an iframe instead?

Tags: jquery, forms, iframe, fancybox

I have a web form on a web shop that I don't want to show like it is, instead I want the selections to be shown in an iframe that now uses FancyBox. Then on a click on a button, show the iframe with the form.

Is this possible somehow?

I got jQUery toggle to work, but that's not all I want. It's the iframe thing that is the important part.

The site is a Wordpress page with Woocommerce.

EDIT: LIke this, but show that div, which in this case is a form, in an FancyBox: http://css-tricks.com/ajax-load-container-contents/

Html:

```
Customize the product <a class="some-class">Here (this opens iframe)</a>
<form class="hide-this">
<input class="select-control" type="radio" name="attribute_lapels" id="notch" value="notch" />
<input class="select-control" type="radio" name="attribute_lapels" id="notch-slim" value="notch-slim" />
        <input id="cancel" value="Cancel" type="cancel" />
        <input id="submit" value="Submit" type="submit" />
</form>
And here comes the product description. Lorem ipsum....
```

Comment: Can we see some code please? Your question doesn't make any sense without some code for context.

Comment: @JoeCullinan is this better?

Comment: Do you understand the differences between opening your form as `inline`, `ajax` and/or `iframe`? If I understood correctly, the form is already on your page, but you want to hide it and then show it inside fancybox (after clicking a link) : that is `inline`. On the other hand, if using `ajax` and/or `iframe`, the form should exists in a separated html page. `ajax` brings the form and makes it part of the DOM while `iframe` only shows the external page through a window (`iframe`) but the page it's totally independent from the page that contains the (html) `iframe` so, what do you want to do?

Comment: @JFK I suppose I want it inline then, since the form is on the same page as the link that when clicked, should show it.